# Trigger Gitlab pipeline on merge request into "main"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a Gitlab pipeline based on a .gitlab-ci.yml file. I want to trigger my pipeline when a merge request is created that merges any branch into the "main" branch. My current .gitlab-ci.yml code triggers the pipeline on any merge request or manual trigger and looks like this:

```
build:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: always # triggers pipeline on merge request
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always # triggers pipeline via web UI "Run pipeline" button
    - when: never # does not trigger pipeline on other events
```

But when I add a condition to the first "if:" to only trigger on a merge into "main" based on online examples, my pipeline does not trigger anymore. I tried two options:

Option 1:

```
build:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      when: always 
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always 
    - when: never
```

Option 2:

```
build:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main"'
      when: always 
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always 
    - when: never
```

The code is accepted and runs fine. But my pipeline does not trigger automatically anymore. Any help to answer my question is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is not available as a predefined CI variable during a merge request. You can use MR specific predefined variables during an MR, here is example using `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME`

[See more about predefined CI vars here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines)

Option 1: Default branch (is not always `main`)

```
build:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always 
    - when: never
```

Option 2: Explicit `main`

```
build:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "main"
      when: always 
    - when: never
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is not available for pipelines triggered for merge requests.

Here is the solution to your requirement

```
build:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      when: always 
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always 
    - when: never
```